# Auto Captitalize Text box cursor auto jump to end

Tags: javascript, html

I use JavaScript to auto-capitalize the input text in HTML. But when i try to edit the middle alphabet, the cursor automatically jumps to the end. How to prevent this ?

This is my code :

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="prodName" id="prodName" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)">
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function upperCaseF(a){
    setTimeout(function(){
        a.selectionStart
        a.value = a.value.toUpperCase();
        a.setSelectionRange(a,a);
    }, 1);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **CSS** `text-transform` property

```js
function upperCaseF(a){
    a.value = a.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```css
.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="prodName" id="prodName" class="uppercase" onblur="upperCaseF(this)">
```